# How does word2vec give one hot word vector from the embedding vector?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I understand how word2vec works.

I want to use word2vec(skip-gram) as input for RNN. Input is embedding word vector. Output is also embedding word vector generated by RNN.

Here’s question! How can I convert the output vector to one hot word vector? I need inverse matrix of embeddings but I don’t have!

Answer (score 0):

The output of an RNN is not an embedding. We convert the output from the last layer in an RNN cell into a vector of `vocabulary_size` by multiplying with an appropriate matrix.

Take a look at the [PTB Language Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) example to get a better idea. Specifically look at lines 133-136:

```
softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [size, vocab_size], dtype=data_type())
softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [vocab_size], dtype=data_type())
logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
```

The above operation will give you logits. This logits is a probability distribution over your vocabulary. [numpy.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) might help you to use these logits to make a prediction.